# How do you update the Knownclientapplications in Azure AD app registration either using powershell,Azure CLI or Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to update the knownclientapplications in Azure AD app , Could anyone help me here. The below command fails. I have also not found a way through CLI as well.

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId "" -KnownClientApplications ""

Set-AzureADApplication: Error occurred while executing SetApplication
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: One or more properties contains invalid values.
RequestId: 55cd4f19-559f-43c4-b04e-cc3a16385e0a
DateTimeStamp: Wed, 22 Apr 2020 17:56:08 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed

Can someone please help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$knowapp = @(
    "<Application ID one>",
    "<Application ID two>"
)
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId "<objectid>" -PublicClient $false -KnownClientApplications $knowapp
```

[image]

Check the `Manifest` of the App in the portal:

[image]

Comment: many thanks let me try, will keep you updated, Meanwhile may i ask what is     -PublicClient purpose here?

Comment: @VivekSingh To prevent your app from being public client, when we use `knownClientApplications`, your app need to be web type.

Comment: You really helped me today. Thank you so much. This is working from Azure Devops pipeline as well.